# How do I transform this regression?

Tags: regression, correlation, data-transformation, biostatistics, count-data

I am researching bladderwrack and whether they can adjust their amount of bladders (small inflated bags of air that develop on their skin) depending on how wave-exposed the surroundings are.

Hence I've created a regression/correlation chart that regresses an individual plant's amount of bladders on the amount of wave exposure it's exposed to. OBS: Wave exposure is calculated using some other data.

Since the plants obviously will develop more sacks/bladders the older they are (due to growing), I've divided the number of bladders each individual had by how much space on their body that they'll have, theoretically, to grow these bladders on. So in other words their bladders are divided by their potential or capacity.

This is what I've got so far:

[image: First version]
[image: Residuals_1]

But as you can see, there is arguably some merit to decreasing the spread when looking at the residuals, which would urge me to transform the regression! The question is just how in that case? And if so, does it just make the chart harder to look at for the human eye? I tried to solve this by putting the natural logarithm on both the x- and y-axis. But I must say that it looks a little weird thinking about what the chart is supposed to refer to:

[image: Version 2]
[image: Residuals_2]

So what would you have done, to in the best way and shape try and convey the statistics here? Would you have kept the regression even or would you have gone with a bar chart? Your hands are free, I'm happy for whatever feedback is given.

Comment: It's a bit tricky to understand what you've done, but if the dependent variable is "number of bags" then I suggest using a count regression model (Poisson or, more likely, negative binomial).  If not, then perhaps a robust regression or quantile regresssion.

Comment: I don't see any compelling reason to start the x axis at 0 and several reasons not to do that. Given a range from about 2.6 to 4.2, its logarithm is almost linear over the range and for that reason is not likely to help.